# Unable to create a tarball: archive/tar: write too long

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, kompose

I am attempting to run a docker-compose file using `kompose up`. I am on Mac OS High Sierra, running latest and greatest versions of everything (Docker CE 17.12.0, VirtualBox 5.2.8 and kompose 1.11.0).

My docker-compose file is:

```
version: '2'

services:
  es:
    build: ./elastic-search
    image: horcle/es
    ports:
     - "9200:9200"
     - "9300:9300"  
    volumes:
     - ./data:/elasticsearch/data
  tab:
    build: ./nlp-tab
    image: horcle/nlptab
    ports:
     - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
     - ./data:/app/data
```

When I run `kompose up` the first image gets successfully built and pushed to Docker.io. However, I get the following error on the second image: `FATA Error while deploying application: k.Transform failed: Unable to build Docker image for service tab: Unable to create a tarball: archive/tar: write too long`

I Googled this, and the issue appears to be with symlinks, which are nowhere in the directory I am using to build this image.

As a test, I did a `docker build -t horcle/nlptab .` followed by a successful push to Docker.io using `docker push horcle/nlptab`. Also, `docker-compose up` runs just fine, as well.

I'm not exactly sure why I cannot run a `kompose up` to do the same thing.

Comment: Are you running on Windows?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I updated my question with relevant info.

Comment: Were you ever able to fix this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: If you have a `node_modules` directory try to `rm -rf node_modules` it first.

Comment: @horcle_buzz please include the Dockerfiles you are using and .env (with redacted private info of course)

Also, please try to run kompose without the volumes and see if it works that way

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a Node.js project. Deleting the node_modules folder (`rm -rf node_modules`) fixed it for me.

Comment: I tried to remove node_modules and reinstall dependencies, still got the same error when I ran `kompose up`

Answer (score 1):

Did you find a solution for this already? if not, try running below command and find out if any symlinks exist.
`ls -laR . | grep -B 5 " -> "`

This may help you find dependencies from node_modules like folders that may be using symlinks.